# Nginx long connection time

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server running on port 80 which is serving static files, and is a proxy frontend for apache on port 8080 and varnish on port 6081.

The setup has been running fine for almost 16 months, and suddenly we started experiencing problems with the connection time to nginx on port 80.

The problem appears if you try telneting to port 80 it from the server itself, so I think it has nothing to do with the network. The problem appears once in every 10 connections, and stalls the connection about 5 seconds.

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a syn flood attack, nothing to do with nginx. I sorted it with a iptables rule.